# Dynamically create a chain of ordered IntegrationFlows

Tags: spring-integration

I'm creating a series of processes that use Spring Integration explicitly using the Java DSL. Each of these processes do different things but they have some of the same processing logic

Example:

```
get
process
deduplicate
emit
```

I would like to essentially create a chain of post processing integration flows that can be enabled/disabled via configuration/profiles.

Example:

```
get
preprocess flow 1 (if enabled)
...
preprocess flow n (if enabled)
process
postprocess flow 1 (if enabled)
...
postprocess flow n (if enabled)
emit
```

I'm pretty sure this doesn't exist yet in SI but thought I'd ask. The only thing i could think of would be to create a bean that created direct message channels on the fly and that, during configuration, i could give to each of the integration flows to use to get their "from" and "channel" message channels.

Example:

```
@Configuration
public class BaseIntegrationConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel preProcessMessageChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel processMessageChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel postProcessMessageChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel emitMessageChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow getDataFlow(MessageChannel preProcessMessageChannel) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(/* some inbound channel adapter */)
                // do other flow stuff
                .channel(preProcessMessageChannel)
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlowChainMessageChannelGenerator preProcessFlowGenerator(
            MessageChannel preProcessMessageChannel, 
            MessageChannel processMessageChannel) {
        IntegrationFlowChainMessageChannelGenerator generator = new IntegrationFlowChainMessageChannelGenerator ();
        generator.startWith(preProcessMessageChannel);
        generator.endWith(processMessageChannel);

        return generator;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow processFlow(
            MessageChannel processMessageChannel, 
            MessageChannel postProcessMessageChannel) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(processMessageChannel)
                // do other flow stuff
                .channel(postProcessMessageChannel)
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlowChainMessageChannelGenerator postProcessFlowGenerator(
            MessageChannel postProcessMessageChannel, 
            MessageChannel emitMessageChannel) {
        IntegrationFlowChainMessageChannelGenerator generator = new IntegrationFlowChainMessageChannelGenerator ();
        generator.startWith(postProcessMessageChannel);
        generator.endWith(emitMessageChannel);

        return generator;
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(1)
@Profile("PreProcessFlowOne")
public class PreProcessOneIntegrationConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow preProcessFlowOne(IntegrationFlowChainMessageChannelGenerator preProcessFlowGenerator) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(preProcessFlowGenerator.getSourceChannel())
                // flow specific behavior here
                .channel(preProcessFlowGenerator.getDestinationChannel())
                .get();
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(2)
@Profile("PreProcessFlowTwo")
public class PreProcessTwoIntegrationConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow preProcessFlowTwo(IntegrationFlowChainMessageChannelGenerator preProcessFlowGenerator) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(preProcessFlowGenerator.getSourceChannel())
                // flow specific behavior here
                .channel(preProcessFlowGenerator.getDestinationChannel())
                .get();
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(1)
@Profile("PostProcessFlowOne")
public class PostProcessOneIntegrationConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow postProcessFlowOne(IntegrationFlowChainMessageChannelGenerator postProcessFlowGenerator) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(postProcessFlowGenerator.getSourceChannel())
                // flow specific behavior here
                .channel(postProcessFlowGenerator.getDestinationChannel())
                .get();
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(2)
@Profile("PostProcessFlowTwo")
public class PostProcessTwoIntegrationConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow postProcessFlowTwo(IntegrationFlowChainMessageChannelGenerator postProcessFlowGenerator) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(postProcessFlowGenerator.getSourceChannel())
                // flow specific behavior here
                .channel(postProcessFlowGenerator.getDestinationChannel())
                .get();
    }
}
```

The idea here being that the invokations of "getDestinationChannel" would create a new channel every time and bridge the output of the last generated channel to the configured "endWith" and every invokation to "getSourceChannel" returns the last created destination channel or, if there are none, the "startWith" channel.

As I write and think about this, I'm starting to think there is probably a better way but thought that I would put this out there for some input.

Thank you.

Comment: checked in a project as a proof of concept using the RoutingSlip pattern mentioned by Gary Russel https://github.com/loesak/spring-routingslip-dynamic-flows-proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently supported directly in the DSL, but the [routing slip](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#routing-slip) might satisfy your needs.

If your `get`, `dedup` etc are individual flows, you can initialize the routing slip at the start of the initial flow to either include, or not, input channels for the preprocessing step(s) in the list in between the channels for the main flows.

Although there is not yet first class support in the DSL, you can use a header enricher to set up the routing slip. The header name is `IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.ROUTING_SLIP`.

**EDIT**

Actually, don't maintain the header yourself; scroll down the reference manual chapter about routing slip to see how to configure the `HeaderEnricher` using Java.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. I'll take a look at the routing slip.

Comment: so is the idea that i have two HeaderEnricher beans, one for my pre-processing flows and one for my post-processing flows and each of those will have a RoutingSlipHeaderValueMessageProcessor configured with a path to RoutingSlipRouteStrategy bean,one for pre-processing and one for post-processing, and the final MessageChannel destination. As my dynamic pre/post-processing integration flows are configured, they register their input channel with the corresponding RoutingSlipRouteStrategy and in addition, instead of supplying an output channel, reference their corresponding HeaderEnricher?

Comment: It took a bit of learning but i was able to get this to work. Thank you. I've checked into github a proof of concept for what i was attempting to do. https://github.com/loesak/spring-routingslip-dynamic-flows-proof

Comment: While doing this POC, i believe I found a bug with SI. The documentation for the Routing Slip pattern says that i can pass Strings, MessageChannels and RoutingSlipRouteStrategys to the RoutingSlipHeaderValueMessageProcessor and if you look at the constructor for the the message processor, it also performs assertions for those objects, however, in the AbstractMessageProducingHandler#getOutputChannelFromRoutingSlip method, it will throw an exception if the returned path is not a String or a RoutingSlipRouteStrategy. I had to change from using MessageChannels in the processor to their bean names.

Comment: Cool; sorry about the learning curve; if you feel some improvements can be made in the documentation, please open a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) and (even better) consider [contributing](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md). The documentation is in simple `asciidoctor` markdown and can be found [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/src/reference/asciidoc/router.adoc#routing-slip). There does seem to be some inconsistency vis-a-vis channel Vs. bean name, so a JIRA issue is appropriate there too.

Comment: If you want to consider proposing your example as a full-blown sample in the [sample repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples), the same contributing guidelines apply and a pull request would be much welcome. Thanks!!

Comment: No need to apologize for the learning curve. its expected and appreciated.   I think the main brain problem i had was that the header had to be set on the message coming into the flow and not part of the flow itself. I'll submit a jira and a pull request for the issue i found. i'll look into submitting a pull request for the example.